# JavaScript is not parsing all of my XML String

Tags: javascript, xml

I have an XML Script which I want to parse in Javascript. Here is the XML string:

```
txt =       "<SFP_AVAILABILITY>";
txt = txt + "   <STATUS>SUCCESS</STATUS>";
txt = txt + "   <NUM_RECORDS>116</NUM_RECORDS>";
txt = txt + "   <MESSAGE>116 records found</MESSAGE>"; 
txt = txt + "   <AVAILABILITY_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP>2015-01-12T15:59:04.443-08:00</AVAILABILITY_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP>";
txt = txt + "   <AVAILABILITY_REQUEST_TIMESTAMP>2015-01-12T15:59:04.330-08:00</AVAILABILITY_REQUEST_TIMESTAMP>";
txt = txt + "   <AVL>"; 
txt = txt + "       <TYPE>OFF</TYPE>"; 
txt = txt + "       <OSPID>934</OSPID>";
txt = txt + "       <NAME>Golden Gateway Garage</NAME>";
txt = txt + "       <DESC>250 Clay Street</DESC>";
txt = txt + "       <INTER>Clay between Front & Davis</INTER>";
txt = txt + "       <TEL>(415) 433-4722</TEL>";
txt = txt + "       <OPHRS>";
txt = txt + "           <OPS>";
txt = txt + "               <FROM>Monday</FROM>";
txt = txt + "               <TO>Friday</TO>";
txt = txt + "               <BEG>4:00 AM</BEG>";
txt = txt + "               <END>10:00 PM</END>";
txt = txt + "               </OPS>";
txt = txt + "           <OPS>";
txt = txt + "               <FROM>Saturday</FROM>";
txt = txt + "               <BEG>7:00 AM</BEG>";
txt = txt + "               <END>10:00 PM</END>";
txt = txt + "           </OPS>";
txt = txt + "           <OPS>";
txt = txt + "               <FROM>Sunday</FROM>";
txt = txt + "               <BEG>9:00 AM</BEG>";
txt = txt + "               <END>10:00 PM</END>";
txt = txt + "           </OPS>";
txt = txt + "       </OPHRS>";
txt = txt + "       <OCC>643</OCC>";
txt = txt + "       <OPER>1160</OPER>";
txt = txt + "       <PTS>1</PTS>";
txt = txt + "       <LOC>-122.3986032,37.79544154</LOC>";
txt = txt + "   </AVL>";
txt = txt + "   <AVL>";
txt = txt + "       <TYPE>ON</TYPE>";
txt = txt + "       <BFID>606022</BFID>";
txt = txt + "       <NAME>Pine St (200-298)</NAME>";
txt = txt + "       <OCC>0</OCC>";
txt = txt + "       <OPER>0</OPER>";
txt = txt + "       <PTS>2</PTS>";
txt = txt + "       <LOC>";
txt = txt + "           -122.4001398109,37.7922631261,-122.4007402937,37.7921866828";
txt = txt + "       </LOC>";
txt = txt + "   </AVL>";
txt = txt + "   <AVL>";
txt = txt + "       <TYPE>ON</TYPE>";
txt = txt + "       <BFID>606032</BFID>";
txt = txt + "       <NAME>Pine St (300-398)</NAME>";
txt = txt + "       <OCC>0</OCC>";
txt = txt + "       <OPER>0</OPER>";
txt = txt + "       <PTS>2</PTS>";
txt = txt + "       <LOC>"; 
txt = txt + "           -122.4011084289,37.7921384027,-122.4024441762,37.7919684168";
txt = txt + "       </LOC>";
txt = txt + "   </AVL>";
txt = txt + "</SFP_AVAILABILITY>";
```

From this it can be seen that there are 3 nodes with the AVL tag. However when I run the following code:

```
if (window.DOMParser)
  {
   parser=new DOMParser();
   xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(txt,"text/xml");
  }
else // Internet Explorer
  {
   xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
   xmlDoc.async=false;
   xmlDoc.loadXML(txt);
  }

 var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("AVL");

 //print out each carparks name
 for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  {
   document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("NAME")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
   document.write("<br>");
  }
```

It only prints out the first AVL nodes name which is: Golden Gateway Garage. This is incorrect as I am expecting 3 names to output as there are 3 AVL nodes.

When running:

```
document.write(x.length);
```

It outputs 1, again, which is not what I am expecting. (expecting 3 to output)

When running:

```
x=xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes;
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
 { 
  if (x[i].nodeType==1)
  {//Process only element nodes (type 1) 
    document.write(x[i].nodeName);
    document.write("<br>");
  } 
}
```

I get the following output:

parsererror 
STATUS
NUM_RECORDS
MESSAGE
AVAILABILITY_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP
AVAILABILITY_REQUEST_TIMESTAMP
AVL

which shows that it is stopping at the first AVL tag.

When I remove the first AVL node in the XML string, the code runs as expected. So the I think the problem lies in parsing that first node properly.

My question is: why is my code only parsing up to the first AVL tag and how do I make it so it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I run your code in IE11, I see:

> Illegal name character. Line: 1, Column 478

And characters 470-479 of the XML string are:

```
Front & Da
```

---

It's failing to parse because your XML is invalid. Here:

```
<INTER>Clay between Front & Davis</INTER>
```

XML can't contain bare ampersands. They have to be escaped:

```
<INTER>Clay between Front &amp; Davis</INTER>
```

I also suspect that there are better ways to get XML into your code that don't involve concatenating the XML together one line at a time. You could store it on your site and load it using an XHR, for example.

I would also advise against using `document.write()` in this day and age.

Comment: That did the trick. I understand that there are better to get XML into my code I was just focusing on getting the info out of the XML first :P. I'm using an api here http://sfpark.org/how-it-works/open-data-page/. What it does is you input a URL and it returns XML. I just copied and pasted the first couple of entries of their XML in my code. Say if I manage to parse the XML from a URL, will I get the same problem with the bare ampersands?

Comment: @FunkasaurusRex Yes, you would still have the same problem. XML has to be valid no matter where you get it from. :)